# Unable to find ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just installed ROS Indigo, along with Gazebo 7 from the separate Gazebo site. According to this page, [Using a specific Gazebo version with ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions#UsingaspecificGazeboversionwithROS), I should be able to install ros-pkgs from Debian with (I believe) the following name: `ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs`.

However, I cannot find this package. I believe I already added the OSR Foundation packages, but perhaps I did not do it correctly. I have

```
http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable trust main
```

in my repository list (I am running Ubuntu trusty). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, or where this package is located?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246687/unable-to-find-ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs/) by [eschulma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1747/eschulma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-30**:
Cross-posted to Gazebo Answers: [Unable to find compiled ros-pkgs for Indigo and Gazebo 7](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14722).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is that line in your "repository list" an actual copy/paste? Because the distribution name is *trusty*, not *trust* (note the `y`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2